# getting this error "Missing compatible node-ios-device library" in appcelator studio

Tags: iphone, titanium, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile

Missing compatible node-ios-device library
2017-01-12T14:10:20.735Z | TRACE  | Error: Missing compatible node-ios-device library
   at loadIosDeviceModule (/Users/salam/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.5.0.GA/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/node-ios-device/ios-device.js:49:9)
   at Object.devices (/Users/salam/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.5.0.GA/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/node-ios-device/ios-device.js:66:2)
   at Object.detect (/Users/salam/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.5.0.GA/node_modules/ioslib/lib/device.js:68:12)
   at devices (/Users/salam/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.5.0.GA/node_modules/ioslib/index.js:102:11)
   at /Users/salam/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.5.0.GA/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:570:21
   at /Users/salam/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.5.0.GA/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:249:17
   at /Users/salam/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.5.0.GA/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:125:13
   at Array.forEach (native)
   at _each (/Users/salam/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.5.0.GA/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:46:24)
   at async.each (/Users/salam/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.5.0.GA/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:124:9)
   at _asyncMap (/Users/salam/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.5.0.GA/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:248:13)
   at Object.map (/Users/salam/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.5.0.GA/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:219:23)
   at _parallel (/Users/salam/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.5.0.GA/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:568:20)
   at Object.async.parallel (/Users/salam/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.5.0.GA/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:598:9)
   at Object.detect (/Users/salam/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.5.0.GA/node_modules/ioslib/index.js:94:8)

### at iOSBuilder. (/Users/salam/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.5.0.GA/iphone/cli/commands/_build.js:292:10)

at Object.run (/Users/salam/.appcelerator/install/6.1.0/package/node_modules/node-appc/lib/subprocess.js:59:8)
   at find (/Users/salam/.appcelerator/install/6.1.0/package/node_modules/node-appc/lib/subprocess.js:96:14)
   at /Users/salam/.appcelerator/install/6.1.0/package/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:987:13
   at Immediate.q.process [as _onImmediate] (/Users/salam/.appcelerator/install/6.1.0/package/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:953:21)
   at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:383:17)

Comment: my node version is v4.6.0

Comment: Any solution, I am facing the same. Node Version 5.10.1. Appcelerator Studio Version: 4.8.1

Comment: I'm actively looking for a solution today. If I discover it, I will post the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found this post. See if it helps. [Reinstalling Appcelerator](https://medium.com/all-titanium/reinstalling-appcelerator-titanium-on-mac-from-scratch-9a2bb6b9b629)